# Separated an array object in php into two new array object php based even and odd index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this on php :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($header_item);
```

The result is :

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
   (
     [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
     [ID_CONDITION] => 1
     [NAMA_CONDITION] => DIRTY
   )

  [1] => stdClass Object
   (
     [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
     [ID_CONDITION] => 2
     [NAMA_CONDITION] => DAMAGE
    )
  [2] => stdClass Object
   (
    [NO_INSPECTION] => 
    [ID_CONDITION] => 
    [NAMA_CONDITION] => CLEAN
   )
  [3] => stdClass Object
   (
    [NO_INSPECTION] => 
    [ID_CONDITION] => 
    [NAMA_CONDITION] => OFF HIRE
 )
)
```

I have case like this, this array will be separated into two new array object  based even and odds index. So I write like this :

```
<?php
    $odd = array();
    $even = array();
    $breakrow = 0;
       foreach ($header_item as $v) {
             if ($breakrow % 2 == 0) {
                array_push($even, $v->NO_INSPECTION);
                array_push($even, $v->ID_CONDITION);
                array_push($even, $v->NAMA_CONDITION);
             } else {
                array_push($odd, $v->NO_INSPECTION);
                array_push($odd, $v->ID_CONDITION);
                array_push($odd, $v->NAMA_CONDITION);
             }
        $breakrow++;
       }
  ?>
```

But I got those new arrays like this :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($even);
echo "<br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($odd);

Array
(
 [0] => 47
 [1] => 1
 [2] => DIRTY
 [3] => 
 [4] => 
 [5] => CLEAN
)
Array
(
 [0] => 47
 [1] => 2
 [2] => DAMAGE
 [3] => 
 [4] => 
 [5] => OFF HIRE
)
```

How can I make like this :

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
       [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
       [ID_CONDITION] => 1
       [NAMA_CONDITION] => DIRTY
      )
    [1] => stdClass Object
      (
       [NO_INSPECTION] => 
       [ID_CONDITION] => 
       [NAMA_CONDITION] => CLEAN
      )
```

AND :

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
       [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
       [ID_CONDITION] => 2
       [NAMA_CONDITION] => DAMAGE
      )
    [1] => stdClass Object
      (
       [NO_INSPECTION] => 
       [ID_CONDITION] => 
       [NAMA_CONDITION] => OFF HIRE
      )
```

Comment: Please, see the edit...

Comment: `list($odd, $even) = array_chunk($header_item, 2);`

Comment: @MarkBaker: That won't work. `array_chunk` will split the input in half (`$odd = [item#0, item#1], $even = [item#2, item#3]`), but the OP needs to distribute them round-robin style (`item#0` into `$even`, `item#1` into `$odd`, `item#2` into `$even` again).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and a simple test of even vs. odd on the key.

```
$header_item = [
    0   =>  'zero',
    1   =>  'one',
    2   =>  'two',
    3   =>  'three',
    4   =>  'four',
    5   =>  'five',
    6   =>  'six',
    7   =>  'seven'
];

$odd = array();$even = array();

array_walk($header_item,function($value,$key) use(&$odd,&$even){
    if ($key%2==0) {
        $even[]=$value;
    }
    else{
        $odd[]=$value;
    }
});

print_r($even);
print_r($odd);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => zero
    [1] => two
    [2] => four
    [3] => six
)
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => three
    [2] => five
    [3] => seven
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :-

```
 $odd = array();
    $even = array();
    $breakrow = 0;
       foreach ($header_item as $v) {
             if ($breakrow % 2 == 0) {
               $even[] = $v;
             } else {
               $odd[] = $v;
             }
        $breakrow++;
       }

  echo '<pre>'; print_r($even).'<br>';

  echo '<pre>'; print_r($odd).'<br>';
```

output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
            [ID_CONDITION] => 1
            [NAMA_CONDITION] => DIRTY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NO_INSPECTION] => 
            [ID_CONDITION] => 
            [NAMA_CONDITION] => CLEAN
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NO_INSPECTION] => 47
            [ID_CONDITION] => 2
            [NAMA_CONDITION] => DAMAGE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NO_INSPECTION] => 
            [ID_CONDITION] => 
            [NAMA_CONDITION] => OFF HIRE
        )

)
```